# How to use backbone-forms in typescript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, backbone-forms

I use backbone.js in my project which is written in typescript. I want to use backbone-forms to create forms but I cannot find any typescript definition file (d.ts) for this backbone plugin. I tried to write my own definition file but I failed to do this with such complicated plugin.

Is there any working definition file for this plugin available anywhere? Or maybe there is some other good plugin to manage forms in backbone with good definition file available?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any working definition file for this plugin available anywhere?

Since its not available on DefinitelyTyped I would assume that it being out there is *very unlikely*.

> I tried to write my own definition file but I failed to do this with such complicated plugin.

You can create a *poor mans* implementation of it quite easily:

```
declare module Backbone {
   export var Form:any;
}
```

This way you are *in no way worse off* than if you were using just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to try to write my implementation once more, but based on code instead of documentation. If I fail once more I'll use your simple implementation.

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to write my own definition file and it works. I'm going to use it in my project. If there are no problems with my definitions after some time I'll try to publish it on Definitely Typed.